# Searching twitter BIO's - but not getting any results back

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

when I start my code, it doesn't return any results, any idea what could be going wrong? I have it searching a yaml file with around 15~ keywords, and if it finds profiles with these keywords, it will notify me of their username + bio.

my yaml file:

```
keywords:
  - Free|free Mint|mint
  - Private|private Discord|discord
  - Discord|discord Invite|invite Only|only
  - Coming|coming soon|Soon
  - DM|dm|Dm for|For collaboration|Collaboration
  - DM|dm|Dm for|For
  - Discord|discord closed
  - No|no Discord|discord
  - No|no Roadmap|roadmap
  - Mint|mint date|Date
  - Founded|founded by|By
  - Created|created by|By
  - Minting|minting
  - Supply|supply
```

I have also tried adding simple words to the yaml file, just to try to get some type of results.

```
# define authentication handler
auth_handler = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)

# Set access tokens
auth_handler.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)

# Creating the API
api = tweepy.API(auth_handler,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Set the path to the YAML file
yaml_path = 'C:\\Users\\CF\\Desktop\\New tweepy testing\\keywords.yaml'

def get_keywords(yaml_path):
    """
    Reads keywords from a YAML file and returns them as a list.
    
    Parameters:
    - yaml_path: The path to the YAML file
    
    Returns:
    - A list of keywords
    """
    # Open the YAML file
    with open(yaml_path, 'r') as f:
        # Parse the YAML file
        data = yaml.safe_load(f)

    # Retrieve the list of keywords from the YAML file
    keywords = data['keywords']

    # Return the keywords
    return keywords

# Get the keywords from the YAML file
keywords = get_keywords(yaml_path)

# Set the starting page number
page = 1

# Set the maximum number of pages to retrieve
max_pages = 100

# Set a flag to indicate when to stop paginating
done = False

# Iterate through the pages of search results
while not done:
    # Search for profiles using the 'users/search' endpoint
    results = api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page)

# Iterate through the search results and print the screen name and biography of each profile
if results:
    for user in results:
        # Encode the screen name and biography in UTF-8 encoding
        screen_name = user.screen_name.encode('utf-8')
        biography = user.description.encode('utf-8')

        # Print the screen name and biography
        print(f'Screen name: {screen_name}')
        print(f'Biography: {biography}')
else:
    print('No results found.')
```

Comment: What if you simplify your code to a single request, ```results = api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page)``` and pass it a single value for q and page? Do you get a result?

Comment: Thanks for the reply caveman. Yeah it does if I do it that way.

Comment: Are you sure your ```while not done:``` block is working? If you can get a single result, it seems like the loop isn't passing the correct values. I don't see you iterating the ```page``` value either.

Comment: I think part of my problem is this exactly. I'm not sure if its working properly. What would the easiest way to test the while not done be?

Comment: If you print ```keywords``` after ```keywords = data['keywords']```, what does it look like. I can't test your code without keys. I would also print ```results``` and see what is in it, or ```print(user)``` after ```for user in results:```.

Comment: printing keywords gives me the text inside of my yaml file

 and printing results/user underneath this line does nothing
if results:
    for user in results:

Comment: Ok, so that leads you to the issue. You have a list of keywords but each list element is formatted like 'Discord|discord Invite|invite Only|only'. Is that the format the API is expecting in ```api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page)```? My guess is no.

Comment: Just moved the print(results) below the results = api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page) and it sends me back around 250 empty [ ].

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a4a8946f0b3c027fa7a9e89b5224328d

Comment: Yeah, your while do isn't iterating and passing the values you think it is. What does ```q=``` and ```page=``` expect? When you hardcode values to test it, what do you assign to those parameters?

Comment: q=Supply page=1

Comment: Also appreciate all of your help Caveman. Been scratching my head for hours.

Comment: No problem. So, in your test that works ```q=Supply```, you are passing a single value. Each item in your keywords list is not a single item. Try printing ```print(api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page))```  above ```results = api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page)``` to see what is actually be passed, or even print(keywords). My guess is your passing the entire list every API call, example ```q=Discord|discord Invite|invite Only|only```

Comment: I went through the yaml file and removed the | between the words and put them on different lines just for an easier way to see. I edited the code to add `api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page)` above the `results = api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page)` and nothing was printed to the terminal.

`while not done:
    # Search for profiles using the 'users/search' endpoint
    api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page)
    results = api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page)
    print(keywords)` ended up just printing my keywords again

Comment: Add ```print(keywords)``` above ```results = api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page)``` and you'll see what is being pased in ```q=keywords```. You may want to use a for loop rather than while do.

Comment: [Photo of what was printed](https://gyazo.com/a458ddea448e8c0daa3a9ca0a1c2c541)

Comment: Ok, so you can see why that wouldn't work right? You are passing that entire list to ```q=```. I would get rid of your while do and use a for loop. Example, ```for word in keywords: ``` and pass ```i``` to ```q=i```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the entire keywords list to `q=` in your API call. Change how you iterate the keywords.

```
# old
while not done:
    # Search for profiles using the 'users/search' endpoint
    results = api.search_users(q=keywords, page=page)

# new
for word in keywords:
    results = api.search_users(q=word, page=page)
```

Comment: This worked! It pulled 20 results! You're the best Caveman thank you. If you're not busy, can you give me a quick speal on how to cycle through new accounts. When I run the code back to back it sends me the same users, with the same information in their bio.

Comment: Phew. Glad it's resolved. You may just be getting the first page of results. Try changing the ```page=``` parameter to 2 or 3 rather than 1 and see what you get. If you get new results, then you'll want to increment the page number on each API call.

Comment: Thank you so much! I switched to a cursor for the searches using the code you helped me with. It's working perfectly now. Now I need to try to build a good database to store the information in so it doesn't show me the same profiles over and over.